# Cannot boot into UPLOAD MODE on SM-T110, kernel panic does not work

Tags: bootloader, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite

I'm trying to boot into UPLOAD MODE on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite 7.0, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I was able to dump this image from the PARAM partition:
[image]

But the tablet just reboots upon a kernel panic. Does anyone know a way to manually trigger this mode? Thanks!

Comment: home + vol dn + pwr

Comment: That's for Download Mode, I'm talking about the UPLOAD MODE that is triggered on special occasions.

Comment: ah okay.. never heard this before https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-s10-sd855/upload-mode/